# Process a large number of java objects

Tags: java, hive, garbage-collection, out-of-memory, bigdata

I am trying to process a large number of rows imported from hive table(hundred millions of rows). As output it will be much more. 
I need to generate new rows if some conditions are valid. But this is not a problem. The problem is how to store these hive rows.
In this moment, I use ArrayList of Objects because the order is very important for my algorithm of inserting new rows, but i get an "GC overhead limit exceeded".

Answer (score 0):

You should be retrieving one page of results at a time into a new ArrayList, processing the rows in that result page, writing new rows as necessary, then load the next result page into a new ArrayList. Garbage Collection (GC) will clean up the older ArrayList.

Ordering of the results should be with an "ORDER BY" clause on your database query.

If you are inserting into the same table and want to avoid reprocessing rows you are adding then you'll need a column on the table to differentiate the new rows from the existing ones - such as an auto-incremented "id" or "date_created".

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Darren Kennedy. I have no idea how to select the rows and be sure i don't lose any in my comparison. For example, I have a date column, stored as String, and I have to look for the next date coresponding to the same values of another two columns. Hope I am clear enough...

Comment: @user0221 Perhaps post your questions about how to write the query as a new SQL question.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to process a large number of rows imported from hive table... but i get an "GC overhead limit exceeded".

You have a couple of options here.  As @DarrenKennedy mentions, if there was some way to process only a page at a time then that would be optimal however it sounds like this isn't an option because of custom sorting.

So you have two possibilities:

- Increase the size of your memory to fit all of the rows.  I suspect that this also isn't an option but I thought I'd state it.
- Process a batch in memory, write it to disk, then process the batch files at the end.  See below.

To process in batches you will need to read a bunch of your input rows that will comfortably fit into memory, sort and filter them, and then write each of the bunches out their own local temporary file.  If you are using cloud systems for this then ephemeral storage would be great for this.

Once you have processed all of the hive input rows, sorted and written them into a bunch of temp files then you will need to go back and read and process the sorted rows doing an insert sort.  Here's some pseudo code:

1. Open all of your temp files using a `BufferedReader` or some such.
2. Read in the first line of all of the files.
3. Output the lowest line from all of the temp files.  Read the next line from that file.
4. Repeat until all of the temporary files have been processed.
5. Close and delete the temp files.

Hope this helps.